# Creating multiple boxplots on the same graph from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib, boxplot

I am trying to create a graph whereby the x axis is the key of the dictionary and the boxplot is from the information inside the dictionary.
My dictionary can have many keys.

```py
Data = {'ABC': [34.54, 34.345, 34.761], 'DEF': [34.541, 34.748, 34.482]}
    
for ID in Data:      
        plt.boxplot(Data[ID])
        plt.xlabel(ID)
plt.savefig('BoxPlot.png')
plt.clf()
```

It however seems to put the box plots on top of each other. I tried iterating the positions value within boxplot with no luck. I would also like to use the key as the xaxis value for each boxplot if possible.

Comment: To avoid unnecessary work on the part of someone willing to answer your question, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, please provide toy datasets (the dictionnaries you are refering to).

Comment: Perhaps this example has the answer to your question: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/boxplot_demo.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
my_dict = {'ABC': [34.54, 34.345, 34.761], 'DEF': [34.541, 34.748, 34.482]}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(my_dict.values())
ax.set_xticklabels(my_dict.keys())
```

[image]

Comment: in jupyter notebooks i get a warning `<ipython-input-94-a3fad8ec34c0>:5: UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
  ax.set_xticklabels(my_dict.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

`labels=` parameter can be used to set x-axis labels in the `boxplot()` call.

```py
my_dict = {'ABC': [34.54, 34.345, 34.761], 'DEF': [34.541, 34.748, 34.482]}
plt.boxplot(my_dict.values(), labels=my_dict.keys());
```

If it were a pandas dataframe, the labels are also applied automatically.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df.plot(kind='box');
```

[image: result]